# Idiom for vehement agreement: "This with [blank] on"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm sure I've heard multiple variations on this expression, but I can't clearly recall any of them, and searching without the key word is impossible. Basically it's a phrase meaning you strongly agree with what was just said and want to emphasize that, possibly following up with more explanation of why that statement was so true.

Example:

> Kittens are the best!
>
> This with [blank] on. They're so fluffy, and their cute little meows melt my heart.

Comment: Do you want us to answer with any idioms that mean *vehement agreement* or to try and find the exact one you semi-remember?

Comment: I'd like the exact one, although, as I said, I feel like it's a phrase that has multiple version, with various nouns filling in the blank. So any examples of this construction would work.

Comment: Right on. Spot on

Comment: "This with knobs on." [BrE (dated)] Note: *knobs* as in door knobs.

Comment: for AmE, I would say "This with bells on".  But I don't have a reference.

Comment: @Mick Yes! That's it. I remember someone also something something like drawer pulls as a variation. Put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Hellion "With bells on" means something along the lines of an enthusiastic statement of intention, along the lines of: "Will you be at the Christmas party?" "Absolutely, with bells on."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"With [brass] knobs on." [BrE (dated)]

[Cambridge Dictionary: with (brass) knobs on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with-brass-knobs-on):

> If you describe something as a particular thing with knobs on, you mean it has similar qualities to that thing but they are more extreme:
>   *Disney World was like an ordinary amusement park with knobs on.*

Answer (score 0):

"In Spades" (meaning "In abundance; very much" is another variant.

It probably comes from the card game contract bridge, where spades are the highest valued suit.  Use in the non-card context started in the 1920s.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-spades.html

From wiktionary:
in spades

```
(idiomatic) In large quantities; to a high degree; to excess, without restraint.  [quotations ▼]

    Last year we harvested almost no potatoes, but this year we're getting them in spades.

(idiomatic) Beyond doubt.
```